# how to create a mbox email file using python

Tags: python, email, base64, email-attachments, mbox

I have a mysql database with email addresses and other data. I need to create specific emails which could be sent to the addresses in the db. The type of email will vary depending on the fields on the db. Each email message will have a pdf attachment taken from a path field in the db. As the emails need to be sent from another computer I have thought of creating an mbox file containing the messages and attachments as base64 ASCII text, which can then be opened in an email program such as evolution and sent from the other computer. I need to get advice and possible examples of how this can be done using python and mysql. Examples of how to convert a email address, message body text and pdf to a ASCII text mbox file would be ideal. Thanks.

Comment: Just a quick tip: check out `email.generator`.

Answer (score 0):

To process a mbox file you could use the `mailbox` module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/mailbox.html but your question is not precise enough and it seems you only need to send emails - for that, creating mbox files is not required, and to make your life easier you could use something like: http://www.mailgun.com/.

Comment: I need to be able to create a email file that could be sent from another computer, thus sending is not required at this stage.

Comment: Why not using message queue to inter process communication and feeding the email sender on another server with messages to be sent? Or, storing the generated email content in the database and fetch it on the other server?

Comment: thanks for the advice. Much appreciated as I am new to this topic. I don't yet know the server or pc from which these emails will be sent. I am trying to make it as simple as possible for another person to send the emails I generated. I also want to keep them away from the data, as they are behind some corporate firewall and arranging access etc would need to be approved etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

To create and manage .mbox files, you can try to use a third-party library [Aspose.Email for Python](https://products.aspose.com/email/python-net?utm_source=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143411/how-to-create-a-mbox-email-file-using-python/58663260#58663260&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=how-to-create-a-mbox-email-file-using-python).

Look at the example below. This approach can help you create .mbox files.

```
# Initialize MboxStorageWriter and pass the above stream to it
writer = MboxrdStorageWriter(dataDir + "ExampleMBox_out.mbox", False)

# Prepare a new message using the MailMessage class
message = MailMessage("from@domain.com", "to@domain.com", "Eml generated for Mbox", "added from Aspose.Email for Python")
message.is_draft = False

# Add this message to storage
writer.write_message(message)

# Close all related streams
writer.dispose();
```

To see more examples, you can go to the [official repository](https://github.com/aspose-email/Aspose.Email-Python-Dotnet/tree/9c4ccb0e4325fe8bb37fb17c347ed96e2647e918/Examples).

I am a Developer Evangelist at Aspose.